# How to use rowlock and readpast with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, optimizer-hints, rowlocking

I have an application which currently reads data from a table using the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBatchOfEmails] 
@BatchSize  INT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WITH ResultSet AS 
    (
        SELECT TOP(@BatchSize) [To], [Subject], [MessageBodyText], [MessageBodyHtml], 
                [From], [ReplyTo], [DateCreated], [EmailId]
        FROM SendMailQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
        ORDER BY TableId
    )
    DELETE FROM ResultSet
    OUTPUT deleted.[To], deleted.[Subject], deleted.MessageBodyHtml, deleted.MessageBodyText,
            deleted.ReplyTo, deleted.[From], deleted.EmailId, deleted.DateCreated 
END
```

As you can see, the stored procedure uses ROWLOCK and READPAST so that a number of rows (controlled by @BatchSize) are read safely by one connection only. After reading, the rows are deleted.

Can anyone point me towards how I might accomplish the same with NHibernate?

Comment: For future references have a look at the following discussion: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104695/how-to-use-readpast-hint-in-nhibernate-when-data-is-selected>